# Determine 2D Convex Hull given 3D Convex Hull

Tags: computational-geometry, convex-geometry

Suppose I have a discrete set of points $S \subset \mathbb{R}^{3}$ and I am given the points which belong to the convex hull of S, $CH(S)$.
Without loss of generality, let us assume that I project the points of $CH(S)$ onto the $yz$ plane.

How would I go about finding the points which belong to the convex hull of the projection $CH(S)$ in the $yz$ plane?

Edit: My hope is to find a procedure which is $O(n)$, where n is the number of points in $CH(S)$.

Answer (score 2):

Since there are simple and fast algorithms for finding the convex hull in 2D, I think that the easiest way is just to project the vertices of the 3D convex hull and find the 2D convex hull of the projected points.

Alternatively, I *think* that the edges of the projected convex hull are the projections of the edges in the 3D convex hull that have one adjacent face pointing in the positive $x$ direction and the other face pointing in the negative $x$ direction, that is, the silhouette edges with respect to the $x$ axis, assuming the faces are oriented consistently.

Comment: I was looking at this picture of a dodecahedron: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/33/Dodecahedron.png

and the set of edges which I think would be the edges of the projected convex hull, do not satisfy your second claim. 

I was also hoping to find a $O(n)$ algorithm, rather than $O(nlogn)$ as you stated in your first suggestion.

Comment: @user1058860,that picture looks ok for what I had i mind; perhaps I haven't been clear.

Comment: @user1058860, note also that the $n$ for the first suggestion is the number of *vertices* of the 3D hull, not the number of original points is $S$.

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you are saying now. Also, there was no restriction that the convex hull of $S$ is $S$, in regards to your comment that $n$ is not the original number of points in $S$